# Confused about FM encoding

Tags: floppy-disk

I'm finding what appear to be two different descriptions of how FM encoding on early floppies worked.

In [this description](https://fliphtml5.com/pdlu/wfhr) (see page 2 if it didn't go there directly) it appears that FM is nothing more than a clock pulse plus another pulse for a 1 and no pulse for a 0. So at the end of every window, the disk is in the "low state" and ready to encode the next window's clock as a rising edge.

However, [Wikipedia's description](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modified_frequency_modulation) *appears* different. It has a clock pulse wither rising or falling at the leading edge of the window, based on the result of the last bit. So in the case of a 1, you might get a rise-then-fall, or a fall-the-rise, depending on what preceded it.

I'm not sure the two are even illustrating the same thing, but I'm confused in any event. Can anyone clarify?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Actually both are correct, but represent a different thing.

One diagram is the actual pulses on wire, the other diagram is the actual magnetic polarity stored on disk. Each pulse generates a single magnetic transition from one state to another, or in reverse, a single magnetic transition generates a pulse on wire.

So the FDC communicates with the drive with pulses of data stream. The floppy drive stores them as magnetic transitions.

So if FDC creates only one pulse for every logic 0 bit, then magnetic polarity toggles once per bit, so consecutive 0 bits on disk toggle between two magnetic polarities. For every logic 1 bit, two pulses are generated, so magnetic polarity toggles twice per bit.

Same when reading data back. Every magnetic transition on disk generates a single pulse to FDC. Therefore, as continuous stream of logic 0 bits toggle polarity once for each bit, there is one pulse for every zero bit, and continuous stream of logic 1 bits toggle polarity twice per bit, so there is two pulses for every bit.

Comment: Spot on. It's the fine line that magnetic recording is inherently different than people assume. It's all about change, not level.

Comment: So then I assume the first reference is the FDC pulses and the second diagram is the resulting fields.

Comment: On the Apple Disk II/Disk Controller II, software writes 1 bits to indicate flux reversals, but the signals from the controller card to the drive represent the flux state to be written.  When in one of the two "writing" modes, the state machine within the Disk Controller II will, once every eight ticks (about four microseconds), either shift the bit pattern in the register by one place or load a new pattern and then flip state if the upper bit of the shift register is set.

Comment: @Raffzahn, Re "all about change, not level." Not disputing that, but the read heads of modern disk drives _are_ level sensitive even if that's not pertinent to how the data are decoded. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_read-and-write_head#Magnetoresistive_heads_(MR_heads)

Comment: @SolomonSlow Sure, _modern_ heads, but the question is about _"FM encoding on early floppies"_, isn't it? And for that it's about detecting a flux change, not a level, as decoding is essentially about edges and their timing.

Comment: @Raffzahn, Yup. That's what it's about.

Comment: So... I'm still a bit confused. If the former diagram is the output of the controller, which I think is what is being said, that seems to imply that the head is a bistable device that changes polarity with each pulse. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, the head is an electromagnet, a coil, and it has no magnetization when no current flows through it. If current flows in one way, it magnetizes with one polarity, and when current flows the other way, it magnetizes with the other polarity. There will be logic chips and electronics converting a pulse to toggle current direction, such as  flip-flops, inverters, and drive transistors.

Answer (score 3):

The process is well documented.  A simple explanation is described in a [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floppy_disk_hardware_emulator#Emulation_process) about floppy drive emulation.  More detailed descriptions are explained in the open source project [FluxEngine](http://cowlark.com/fluxengine/doc/technical.html):

> - nominal rotation speed is 300 rpm, or 5Hz. The period is 200ms.
> - a pulse, as generated by the floppy drive electronics, is 150ns to 800ns long.
> - a 12MHz tick is 83ns.
> - MFM HD encoding uses a clock of 500kHz. This makes each recording cell 2us, or 24 ticks. For DD it’s 4us and 48 ticks.
> - a short transition is one cell (2us == 24 ticks). A medium is a cell and a half (3us == 36 ticks). A long is two cells (4us == 48 ticks). Double that for DD.
> - pulses are detected with +/- 350ns error for HD and 700ns for DD. That’s 4 ticks and 8 ticks. That seems to be about what we’re seeing.
> - in real life, pulses start going astray on a 3.5” drive after about 128 ticks == 10us. I haven’t tried with a 5.25” drive yet as I don’t have a 5.25” scratch disk.

More detailed magnetic flux theory can be found by exploring the [FluxEngine](http://cowlark.com/fluxengine/doc/technical.html) website and wiki, and it should be noted that the use of the word "cell" on the [FluxEngine](http://cowlark.com/fluxengine/doc/technical.html) site could be misleading, as noted in the following comments I've roughly quoted here from @Raffzahn:

*There are no cells on magnetic media. The problem with the term 'cell' is that it is commonly associated with a predefined fixed item. That's as well the image above description invokes. Except there are no predefined cells on magnetic media. It's continuous. Nor does writing create them, as all magnetic media is about timing, and timing varies within a drive and between drives.
What is written in 2µs in one drive may presented as 2.1µs in another or 1.9 while still being within spec. Varying time means varying length as well. All of this will add up over the length of a track, and items may cover more or less than one of these cells. Some learners may be confused when magnetic media is described as cells, as they assume them to be something like a bit cell in a RAM or FLASH. The description would have been more accurate if he had simply abstained from introducing that term and stayed with duration in µs or maybe ticks/clock duration(s). Cells are an unnecessary addition.*

Comment: Except, there are no cells on magnetic media.

Comment: @Raffzahn -Yea, he doesn't appear to define what a "cell" means in the short screen cap that I posted.  It's been a few years since I went down the rabbit hole on his website, but I do recall reading info on there that went specifically into the magnetic fluctuations that are written to and read from the disk.  Perhaps I should remove the screen shot, and leave the digging to the adventurous reader?  I know my response was late, and would be too minimal without the posted screen shot, but I felt this valuable resource shouldn't be left out of the discussion...

Comment: Naa. Your Answer is fine. I was just nitpicking.

Comment: @Raffzahn - Just checking.  IMO you are the prevalent guru here, and I thank you for your input!

Comment: @Raffzahn - Well now I feel ignorant (or at least lazy lol) since I re-read the text and he clearly defines the definition of a "cell" in the fifth bullet point...

Comment: Me not any kind of guru, just an old guy dragged down by a white beard, fostering a pet peeve about a word :) Problem with the term 'cell' is that it is commonly associated with a predefined fixed item. That's as well the image above description invokes. Except there are no predefined cells on magnetic media. It's continuous. Nor does writing create them, as all magnetic media is about timing, and timing varies within a drive and between drives. What is written in 2µs in one drive may presented as 2.1µs in another or 1.9 while still being within spec. Varying time means varying length as well.

Comment: All of this will add up over the length of a track. In addition, not even his description about a cell is consistent, as items may cover more or less than one of these cells. I've experienced many learners being confused when magnetic media is described as cells, as they assume them to be something like a bit cell in a RAM or FLASH (I think there were even questions on this site due exactly this). Above description would be perfectly fine if he had simply abstained from introducing that term and stayed with duration in µs or maybe ticks/clock duration(s). Cells are an unnecessary addition.

Comment: @user3840170 - Thanks for the edit.  I only had limited time to add my answer before I had to leave, and while it would have been faster and better for me to copy and paste the text, I couldn't get a good grab of the table in my browser to my clipboard for some reason, so I just quickly screen capped and cropped it lol.  Thanks again...

Comment: @Raffzahn - I feel as if your comments would be valuable to anyone perusing the website I linked, so it seems like I should append selections from your comments to my original answer, giving you credit of course...

Comment: @Raffzahn - ...With your permission.

Comment: Go ahead, perfect fine with me - I'm doing the same all the time. On a less ranty level, the term cell has been historically used in conjunction with floppies (WD for example _did_ use it as well in the 1771 data sheet, before, I think, even IBM did), but it seems quite misleading looking back with today's canon of everything quantised and digital.

Comment: @Raffzahn - Yea, I guess me being used to the historical usage is why I sort of gloss past the term without a second thought, since I am well familiar with magnetic technologies(I actually used to repair reel to reels lol) and realize that "cell" is an awful term to use when applied to analog technology of any sort.  I guess I've always felt as if the use of the term was just used to help make it easier to understand for those more familiar with the digital-only world.  Will add selected text, and feel free to edit yourself as you see fit.  Thanks!

Comment: @Raffzahn - Ok, think I got a final edit. Alter as you see fit! Thanks!

Comment: @Raffzahn - Forgot to mention, that your grey beard shouldn't drag you down.  It should, in fact, be quite uplifting!  I'm pretty sure that grey beards are number one in the periodic table; quite uplifting, but unfortunately, also quite flammable....

Answer (score 1):

Some descriptions of magnetic formats regard areas of the disk that are magnetized in one direction as a 1, and those magnetized in the other direction as a zero, while others interpret a time slice in which a *transition* occurs as a 1, and a time slice in which no transition occurs as a zero.

The latter interpretation is more common, and in many cases describes how data is communicated over the cable between a floppy drive and a controller, but the former describes how data is physically stored on disk.  Interestingly, the Apple Disk Controller II sends the former kind of signalling to the drive when writing data, but expects to receive the latter form from the drive when reading.